# Format Scrapy image field output in XML

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I managed to scrape all image URLs and they output the image result field correctly like so:

```
'image': [{'checksum': 'c2cc74b428a3fb18d6ac8d47978c98cb',
        'path': 'full/33032b22901636542bef9dd6d3b6e98d1f7eb463.jpg',
        'url': 'image-url.com/ID7b6b6700-0000-0500-0000-000003422a59.jpg'},
       {'checksum': '3c21a99a0d45870e4ab79f201f97c35e',
        'path': 'full/8f7d216aee4942987860c77efff0595bfcdccdf9.jpg',
        'url': 'http://image-url.com/ID7b6b6700-0000-0500-0000-000003422a5b.jpg'}]
```

I'm trying to wrap the image path in a XML node `<image>`, but I can't really figure out what the correct approach would be.
Right now, I guess the output is the way it is because it's an iterable value that comes from a list:

```
<image>
<value>
<url>
http://image-url.com/ID0df36700-0000-0500-0000-00000346f2d2.jpg
</url>
<path>full/8df264408df9bb24e7d750f61828239534d96497.jpg</path>
<checksum>d87852609293934aa91edd649d3051aa</checksum>
</value>
</image>
```

I'd like the output to be the following for each image path as I don't need the other fields:

```
 <image>full/8df264408df9bb24e7d750f61828239534d96497.jpg</image>
```

I've tried to apply a serializer function to format the field, but I can't really get it to output a new node per image path.
Could I have some pointers to the right direction?

Comment: Are <value> and <url> children of <image> ?

Comment: <value> is a direct child of <image> and <url>, <path> and <checksum> are children of <value>. Sorry if the formatting is off

Answer (score 1):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root[0]:
    if child.tag == url:
        url = child.text
    if child.tag == path:
        path = child.text
    print child.tag,child.text
```

if "image" is root then "value" will be root[0]
"url" and "path" will be root[0]'s child

if you have lots "value", you can use for loop to change root[x].

Comment: That's a nice workaround. However, I'm still going to try and do it through scrapy and not editing the final XML output. Will update when I come to a conclusion